# Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Album) could not be initialized

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i have installed skeleton application its working well and i have created New module.Module name 'Album'.after create module trying to run the code i am  receiving error.
 here post my code:

module.php

```
<?php
namespace Album;

 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
 {
     public function getAutoloaderConfig()
     {
         return array(
             'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                 __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
             ),
             'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                 'namespaces' => array(
                     __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                 ),
             ),
         );
     }

     public function getConfig()
     {
         return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
     }
 }
 ?>
```

module.config.php:

```
<?php
return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
         ),
     ),
     'view_manager' => array(
         'template_path_stack' => array(
             'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
         ),
     ),
 );
 ?>
```

i am getting error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Album) could not be initialized.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php:195 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(169): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
```

Comment: anybody know the answer and knows any idea please let me known.thanks in advance

Comment: Filename of module.php should be `Module.php` unless that's a typo. If that's not it we'll need more info.

Comment: @Tim Fountain i changed.but still i am getting same error.

Comment: We need more info. The error means ZF can't find your Album's module class. What is the full path to the album Module.php?

Comment: follow the come zf2 user guide url copy code from zf2 userguide.

Comment: Have you added your module name (Album) in config/application.config.php?

Comment: thank u @cristiano Casciotti. now added Module Name

Comment: Cristinano casciotti added same issues

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me.
Just udpdate autoloading in composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
            "Album\\": "module/Album/src/"
        }
    },
```

And then run:

```
php composer.phar update
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem I resolved it by correct the namesapce of the module
The namespace is the name of the folder that contain the module.php, make sure they have the same name

Answer (score 1):

You need disable config caching by default

You can run:

```
$ composer development-enable
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Case** of the filename 'module.php'.  On macOS, the filesystem can find module.php and Module.php.  But if you deploy to a case sensitive file system (say some variant of Linux eg Centos) you will get this error.